# Confusion on locally compact Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

I am confused on the following theorem. Let X be a space. Then X is locally compact Hausdorff if and only if there exists a space Y satisfying the following conditions: 
(1) X is a subspace of Y
(2) The set $Y-X$ consists of a single point.
(3) Y is a compact Hausdorff space.

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual topology and the subspace topology on $(0,1)$. The interval $(0,1)$ is locally compact, however the compactification requires two points, namely $0$ and $1$. Therefore $Y - (0,1)$ will consist of 2 points not one. I am very confused, where did I go wrong?

Also, I am having trouble showing that the compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ is homomorphic to $S_{1}$. I can show that the circle is compact and Hausdorff under the supspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equipped with the topology that is induced by the Euclidean metric. But I need a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ into the circle.

Comment: @k.stm Post your comment as an answer. You could add that the circle is a one point compactification of an open interval. That will provide a clue to the OP's "also" question.

Comment: @k.stm hat helped greatly. So, $[0,1]$ is a compactification of the open interval $(0,1)$, but like you said not the only way to compactly a space. Since the open interval is homomorphic to the reals, the circle is basically a one point compactification of (0,1). Now I will just map $(0, 2\pi)$ into $S_{1} - (1,0)$ by $f(x) \rightarrow (cos(x),sin(x))$. Which should do it?

Comment: Yeah, that should do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Topologically, the standard open interval is the same as the real line. To see this, use the maps
$$(-1..1) → ℝ,~x ↦ \frac x {1 - |x|},\quad\text{and}\quad ℝ → (-1..1),~x ↦ \frac x {1 + |x|},$$
and note that $(0..1) \cong (-1..1)$ by some affine transformation.

Of course $[0..1]$ is also a compactification of $(0..1)$  – if you understand a “compactification” of a space to merely be a compact space in which the original space can be embedded. But then it’s not the only one and it’s not the *one-point compactification*. In general, there are many ways to compactify a space in this sense.

In fact, $(0..1)$ can be compactified to a circle. To see this, just think about how you would create a loop out of a loose string and some glue. If you know about trigonometric functions, or better yet, the complex exponential, you’ll see how to do this mathematically.

If you want to compactify $ℝ$ directly, you can go for the stereographic projection.